# AJAX requests made by another domain's javascript file

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, jsonp, same-origin-policy

Have two Visual Studio's running on same computer with following URLs:

1. http://localhost:47503 (web api, #1)
2. http://localhost:12345 (client that calls above web api, #2)

Client (#2) hard codes Site #1's `<script src="http://localhost:47503/file.js"></script>`. Inside the file.js is a single function:

```
function GetData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:47503/api/autos',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "a": '_1', "b": 'TEST', "c": "val c" },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://localhost:47503/api/autos?a=_1&b=TEST&c=value+c.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Thought that since script was loaded from Client #1, that it could be invoked from Client #2 hence bypassing the same origin policy in a way? Script from Client #1 calls back to Client #1. JSONP and CORS are known solutions to problem but want to know if above is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thought that since script was loaded from Client #1, that it could be invoked from Client #2 hence bypassing the same origin policy in a way?

No, this is not possible. The origin is always that of the document, not the individual script tags. This is how you are able to load libraries like jQuery from a CDN, but make AJAX requests to your own server.

---

On a side note, even if the origin were determined by the script making the call (which it never is), your code still wouldn't work, since it would actually be jQuery making the AJAX call.

Comment: Question was inspired by how Google Adsense works (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdSense). Users add javascript to their sites and it makes remote calls back to Google's servers to display an ad. Any idea how to mimic this behavior?

Comment: @invulnarable27 It's easy with JSONP, which I think is what Wikipedia is describing.

Comment: great thanks, wanted to make sure I covered all my bases

Answer (score 0):

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Your server #1 can explicitly tell to the web browser that it acctually accepts requests comming from an other domain, by adding the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to its HTTP responses.

Comment: Those XML files are only for deprecated and obsolete plugins. Unless using Flash (ugh) or Silverlight (eww, gross) just skip those.

Comment: he can use the header